# How to disable the sp_helptext

Tags: sql-server

There is alignment issue happening due to using `sp_helptext`,
So that we do not allow to execute the `sp_helptext` cmd.

Which way can we prevent the execution `sp_helptext`?

Comment: What possible problem could running `sp_helptext` have? That sounds like a really strange thing to do.

Comment: Why do you want that? What does `alignment issue` mean? If you don't call that stored procedure you won't have anything that needs aligning. If you mean `compliance` there are no problems caused by `sp_helptext`.As [the permissions section clearly explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) only users that *already* have explicit permission to access an object's definition can use it

Comment: Disabling `sp_helptext` won't do anything if users still have ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, or VIEW DEFINITION on an object.

Comment: You have a management and people problem - no amount of "anti-functionality' will improve this situation. Train your people, implement professional practices, stop using lazy post-development code management.

Answer (score 1):

you can revoke execution of `sq_helpdesk` from users

```
 DENY execute on sp_helptext to [DomainName\UserName] ;
```

Comment: Why do that though? The docs explain that only users with the ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, or VIEW DEFINITION permissions can use it.

Comment: You'll need to use `DENY` instead of `REVOKE`. The `public` role has execution permissions.